# safari on ipad - image resizing

Tags: ipad, safari, retina-display, easeljs

im working with easeljs on ipad in safari.
the problem is that i have sprites with upto 30 frames
when i set the size of each of the frames to `400x225` width i should be getting is `400*30` but what i actually get is `400*30/2` and this is i think because of the `retina display`
but when i set the each of the frames to `800x550` then width i actually get is 800*30/4 ultimate reducing the size to same 400*30/2
so when i render this sprite on a canvas which is `600` in width it pixelates
what can be done?